# ERRORCODE0: 10501 while connecting to paypal do direct

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

How does one resolve the following error when trying to connect to the paypal sandbox account

```
[TIMESTAMP] => 2013-05-03T15:13:47Z
[CORRELATIONID] => c51f05505c8b5
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 76.0
[BUILD] => 5715372
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10501
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Configuration
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
[AMT] => 200.00
[CURRENCYCODE] => USD
```

As far as I can tell from reading all the other issues here, the only possible solution is to post on stackoverflow and wait for someone to magically fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The 10501 error happens when you are trying to use an API call that you do not have permission on.

If you are using the facilitator account in the sandbox, it probably doesn't have the PayPal API access enabled on it.

Make a different business sandbox account, and use the API credentials generated from that account, and you should be good to go.